# SSH тунель windows

Tags: windows, сервер

столкнулся с такой проблемой, установил open ssh сервер на windows server 2019, при попытке создания тунеля к нему просто зависает ssh (после ввода пароля юзера)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю в чем может быть проблема

Comment: А что по-вашему ещё должно происходить? Туннель успешно создан и работает.

Comment: Проблема в том что он не работает

Comment: По 14727 порту не подключается

Comment: Как вы определили, что он не работает? Где, как и откуда вы пытаетесь подключиться к 14727 порту? Вы не забыли запустить на своём компьютере какой-нибудь сервер, который будет слушать 3306 порт и принимать подключения?

Comment: Не забыл, я рдп кинул на 3306 порт, при конекте на 34.125.33.164:14727 - ничего не происходит... При локальном подключении все работает, то есть 127.0.0.1:3306

Comment: При коннекте на 34.125.33.164:14727 ничего и не должно происходить, потому что по умолчанию порт биндится на локальный интерфейс и не принимает подключения извне. Если вы хотите разрешить подключения со всех сетевых интерфейсов, то пропишите `-R 0.0.0.0:14727:localhost:3306`

Comment: Кроме того, убедитесь, что на удалённой стороне не стоит никакого межсетевого экрана, который запрещает вам подключаться к порту 14727

Comment: Никакого экрана нет, фаирволы вырублены, всё открыто, такое чувство что клиент зависает

Comment: Вижу, что вы всё ещё не прописали `-R 0.0.0.0:14727:localhost:3306`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pTDSSeq ничего не поменялось, вообще windows openssh server поддерживает тунели?

Comment: Конечно поддерживает, чё б не поддерживать-то. Вы точно-точно уверены, что порт не блокируется никаким межсетевым экраном? Если вместо туннеля запустить на порту 14727 что-нибудь другое (хоть банальный netcat) — подключение будет идти?

Comment: Ну а ещё можно добавить опцию `-v` и убедиться в наличии сообщения `debug1: remote forward success for` для подтверждения, что туннель работает и проблема в чём-то другом

Comment: Проверял, не идет, не понимаю уже ничего... Из вне по 3306 конект идет... Бред

Comment: Уже порт перекинул, ничего https://imgur.com/a/yWuRFyF

Comment: Ваш локальный порт не имеет никакого значения, если удалённый порт 14727 в любом случае блокируется удалённой стороной. Если я правильно понимаю [документацию Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls), по умолчанию входящие подключения всё-таки блокируются и их нужно явно разрешать

Comment: Говорю же фаирвол вырублен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ssh_config добавить следующее:

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
```